# How can I quickly update my email address for the site?

Tags: discussion

If I find out that I’ve accidentally made a bunch of user accounts and want to edit them one by one and then merge them -  I find it’s a lot easier if they all share the same email address.

Is there a simple URL our way to edit the associated email once I’m signed in to a specific account?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in addition to the Edit controls for your profile page that you get when you click your icon, you can also bookmark this address:

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/email/settings/current

If you just want to get to the main profile page, this link will work:

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current